# Map method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

```
items.map((itemsvalue, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li key={index}>
        <button className="deleteBtn" onClick={DeleteBtn}>
          X
        </button>
        {itemsvalue}
      </li>
    </>
  );
});
```

Here items is an array of strings.
How can i access index value in the DeleteBtn function???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an inline function for the onClick handler. I have changed function name to `onClickDelete` , because its a common practice to name the click handlers as `onClickDelete`, `handleDelete` .

```
items.map((itemsvalue, index) => {
  return (
    <>
      <li key={index}>
        <button className="deleteBtn" onClick={() => onClickDelete(index)}>
          X
        </button>
        {itemsvalue}
      </li>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: If the answer helps addressing your question . can you accept and upvote it :-)

Comment: I am not able to upvote it, don't know why. It's saying that i need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass index as the second argument in map

[MDN lINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters)